# How can I use angular ng-repeat to generate rows of 4?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple ng-repeat generating image divs. I want them to come out in rows of 4 instead of one long vertical list. How can I do this?

```
<div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
    <div>
        <h3> {({ artist.fields.title })} </h3>
        <img src="{({ artist.fields.link })}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this

```
<div style="width:800px;">    
    <div ng-repeat="artist in artists" style="width:200px;float:left;">
        <div>
            <h3> {({ artist.fields.title })} </h3>
            <img src="{({ artist.fields.link })}" />
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

By having a container with a fixed width, and having each element inside be 1/4 of that width you can achieve what you want.

Of course, inline styles shouldn't be used in real code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$index property](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to add a tag every 4th item. Then use some CSS to display items as desired:

```
<div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
    <div class="someClass">
        <h3> {({ artist.fields.title })} </h3>
        <img src="{({ artist.fields.link })}" />
    </div>
    <br ng-if="artist.$index % 4 == 0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use css properties. attach a class to the div with a float:left attribute, and insert a br tag after every 4th div

Comment: My question is, how can I tell angular to insert a `float:left` attribute and then insert a `<br>` tag after every fourth div?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using bootstrap?
If yes, this thread could do a help:

[Bootstrap's grid columns number per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863495/bootstraps-grid-columns-number-per-row)

doc for bootstrap grid layout:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Comment: No, I am using angularjs.